# Set textbox content prefix and postfix via jquery and make it un-editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field for the user to insert their own wordpress shortcode. I would like the characters `[` and `]` to wrap around their text inside the input box. I don't want them to be able to remove the brackets, and they should always be there.

For example in the input box when they first arrive on the page, it would just have this `[]` then when they focus on that textbox, the cursor should stay between the brackets, and they should't ever be able to delete the brackets.

Comment: Is your question just "is this possible"? If so, then the answer is yes.

Comment: No... That was the last line of my question. If you read the first paragraph, it states what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

For some reason, I cannot get this code to work in jsFiddle, but I have extensively tested this code in the following browsers:

Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m - Working

FireFox 19 - Working

FireFox 24 - Working

Safari 5.1.7 - Working.

IE10 - Working

IE9 - Working

IE8 - Partially Working (cannot select text between brackets)

IE7 - Partially Working (cannot select text between brackets)

I did find that there was a reported potential security concern for the older versions of IE when using the createTextRange function which is likely why the code is not working in these versions.

There have been several changes made to the original code that was posted.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var setBrackets = function (elem) {
            var text = elem.value;
            text = text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            text = "[" + text + "]";
            elem.value = text;
        };

        var selectRange = function (elem) {
            var endPos = elem.value.length - 1;
            var startPos = 1;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                if (typeof elem.selectionStart === "number") {
                    elem.selectionStart = startPos;
                    elem.selectionEnd = endPos;
                } else if (typeof elem.createTextRange !== "undefined") {
                    elem.focus();
                    var range = elem.createTextRange();
                    range.collapse(true);
                    range.select();
                }
            }, 1);
        }
        function checkEmpty(elem) {

            if (elem.value.length > 2) {
                setBrackets(elem);
                selectRange(elem);
            }
            else {
                selectRange(elem);
            }
        }
    </script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="test" value="[]" onblur="setBrackets(this)" onfocus="checkEmpty(this)"/>
</body>
```

I hope this works for you.  Please let me know if there's something I can help you with.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, you're doing it right, but it seems as though I found something that actually works in IE that doesn't work in chrome... strange, I know.  Normally these things are the other way around.  I'm working on a fix for you.

Comment: Ok, this one works in Chrome and IE, tested in both.

Comment: Here is the new fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/992tq/1/ I don't see it working still. Not sure why not. I don't understand most of your code, otherwise I'd try and tweak and troubleshoot it myself.

Comment: Ok, I'll check into it again.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'll take your code and try it on a live site and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: man... lol, guess it is hard to tell from my user name.  no problem, if you have any other trouble let me know... and if it works for you, please vote/accept my answer to help me out on here.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution, when you need to add a brackets in your text-field / phone number field

http://ashfaqahmed.net/jquery-add-prefix-postfix-on-phone-number-field/